# Prononciation de la lettre f-finale dans le mot clef

Tags: prononciation, étymologie, histoire

I don't know if I am missing something rather basic. Why the final f is pronounced in œuf, bœuf, neuf, chef and not in **clef** ? I guess it has to do with the same pronunciation of **clé** but still it looks strange to me.

Comment: Vous devriez trouver votre bonheur en bas de cette page *https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clef* qui semble être une des plus fournie du site. Au-delà du *f*, du *z* après le *e* ou de l’absence d'une quatrième lettre, connaître les locutions qui utilisent ce mot éclaire la compréhension du français.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something that answers partially to my question. Still no explanation is provided.

[image]

https://books.google.fr/books?id=vMNDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA238#v=onepage&q&f=false

**EDIT** par souci d'exhaustivité réponse fournie dans un autre forum (https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/prononciation-de-la-lettre-f-a-la-fin-des-mots-ex-oeuf-boeuf-neuf-chef-clef/)

D’après orthonet, le site édité par le Conseil international de la langue française (CILF), le « f » de clef se prononçait, en ancien français – exactement comme pour œuf et bœuf.  En synthèse, l’ancien français nous aurait légué la forme « une clef » (le « f » n’est plus prononcé depuis longtemps), et « des clés » correspondant au son prononcé au pluriel.

C’est donc « clés », pluriel de « clef » à cette époque, qui aurait plus tard donné « clé » au singulier, autre forme de « clef ».

Le mot « clef » ferait donc l’objet d’une double exception : comme pour les bœufs et les œufs, le « f » est conservé au pluriel (des clefs), mais contrairement à eux, « clef » peut aussi s’écrire « clé ». Au pluriel, on trouve donc naturellement deux orthographes possibles : « clefs » et « clés »…

J'inclus aussi le commentaire de @personne

> Vous devriez trouver votre bonheur en bas de cette page
> cnrtl.fr/definition/clef qui semble être une des plus fournie du site.
> Au-delà du f, du z après le e ou de l’absence d'une quatrième lettre,
> connaître les locutions qui utilisent ce mot éclaire la compréhension
> du français.

Comment: *clefs* se prononce *clé*

Comment: Tu pourrais faire remarquer que par rapport à l'*Essay d'une grammaire française* de Chiflet dont tu montres un extrait, la prononciation a parfois changé : *couvreche**f***, *un oeu**f** tout frais*, *des habits nœu**fs** (neufs)* où le *F* final est maintenant prononcé, optionnel pour *cer**f*** ou disparu pour *ner**f***...